# Grep from file - failing on spaces

Tags: unix, grep, putty

The command I am trying to execute is

```
fgrep -h -f "list.csv" input.csv > output.csv
```

The

For simplicity, lets say the list file contains two items:
content1
"c o n t e n t 2"

Both of these match in the input file. For example if I type

```
fgrep -h "c o n t e n t 2" input.csv
```

I receive a result. However, when I use the first command it only matches content1.

My suspicion is that this is a result of the quotes around the string with spaces in the list file. How can I get grep to match the contents within the quotes and ignore the quotes themselves?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need quotes around spaced entities when you use `fgrep`. `fgrep` takes each line literally already. It's only in the command line that you need quotes in order to disambiguate a string from extra command line arguments. Your file can just be:

```
content1
c o n t e n t 2
```

Comment: I am not creating the list file manually, it is a large file that I receive. I suppose I'd need to either find a way of removing the quotes, or of excluding the quotes from the fgrep.

Comment: Unfortunately that's so. One thing you might do to keep your command a one-liner is use `sed`: `sed 's/^"\(.*\)"$/\1/' input.csv` removes quotes from all the lines wrapped in quotes. I'm too rusty on shell pipes to figure out how to "inject" this into your command—"command interpolation" via `$(...)` or something?—but I'm sure you can figure that out.

Comment: This answer is correct in that the grep works properly when the file has no quotes. I used the command tr -d '"' to remove all quotation marks from the list file and then the result was accurate.